# Will Apple Pay Web work if the domain of the server on which it is developed does not coincide with production?

Tags: ios, payment, applepay, apple-developer, applepayjs

There is a server on which I develop a website with apple pay web, there is a server for production.
Their domains are different. For in apple pay I have registered a domain, the one that will be on the prod server.
I am trying to make test payments on a virgin server (with a different domain), the system window just crashes.

"Apple Pay Not Completed
This website was not able to complete the payment"

Everything is at https, certificates are all there, everything is done for the production domain

Does apple pay web work if domains are different? Do I need to do anything? Register to something to work on the development domain ??

Comment: Trying to do the same, not working at the moment and getting the same error message. Please comment if you have found a solution.